# $Trash view always empty in Lotus Notes via COM/C#

Tags: c#, com, lotus-notes

I have an issue where the $Trash view always appears to contain no Documents when using the COM API in Lotus Notes.  All other views seem to behave as expected.  Documents are definitely in the view according to the Lotus Notes client itself and have not been hard-deleted.

Is there some reason why these documents are not available from the $Trash view via the COM API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trash view in Notes is actually $SoftDeletions, not $Trash. Problem solved.